# Buscar nombres en un Select Option Html Php MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo este problema, quiero crear un buscador de nombres de clientes que sea auto completado en un select option aquí mi código:

```
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>

                <select class="form-control" id="seleccionarCliente" name="seleccionarCliente" required>

                <option value="">Seleccionar cliente</option>

                <?php

                  $item = null;
                  $valor = null;

                  $categorias = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);

                   foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) {

                     echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'">'.$value["nombre"].'</option>';

                   }

                ?>

                </select>

                <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarCliente" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar cliente</button></span>

              </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Cual es exactamente la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Creo yo que es mejor utilizar algo ya creado, que podría ser bootstrap selected... link => [Bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

la documentación es buena y te demoraras 5 min en implementarlo.

saludos